# Passing data to widget ListView using intent.putExtra not working. (Using RemoteViewsFactory)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-listview, android-widget

I am currently working on creating a home screen widget with ListView using AppWidgetProvider, RemoteViewsFactory, and RemoteViewsService.

**onRecipeItemClick**

This method is connected to each recipe card views and upon user clicking one of the cards, user enters an activity for that recipe and widget should be updated with the ingredients for that clicked recipe.

```
public void onRecipeItemClick(Recipe recipe) {
// some code to navigate to different activity
        updateWidget(this, recipe);
}
```

**updateWidget**

recipe.getIngredients() returns list of Ingredient objects and that list is passed as intent Extra.

```
    public static void updateWidget(Context context, Recipe recipe){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecipeAppWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra("ingredients", (Serializable) recipe.getIngredients());
        int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, RecipeAppWidgetProvider.class));
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

**onRecieve**

In the provider class, I have variable 'ingredients' and its value is updated from SerializableExtra of intent. From log statements, I have confirmed that proper list of Ingredient objects are stored to 'ingredients' variable via onReceive method.

```
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getSerializableExtra("ingredients") != null){
            ingredients = (List<Ingredient>) intent.getSerializableExtra("ingredients");
            AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, RecipeAppWidgetProvider.class);
            mgr.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(mgr.getAppWidgetIds(cn),R.id.widget_list_view);
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

**onUpdate**

I use the variable 'ingredients' as intent Extra and set the remote adapter here. From debugging, I confirmed that 'onUpdate' is called after 'onRecieve' is called and 'ingredients' variable is filled with list of ingredients passed from MainActivity.

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.recipe_app_widget);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, RecipeWidgetRemoteViewsService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetId);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            intent.putExtra("ingredients", (Serializable) ingredients);

            views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list_view, intent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.widget_list_view);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
```

So this is my approach of passing list of ingredient objects from MainActivity to provider to RemoteViewFactory. I think my code works updateWidget() -> onRecieve() -> onUpdate(). But from logging the intent.getSerializableExtra("ingredients") in 'onGetViewFactory' method from RemoteViewsService class, data is lost for some reason. Also, while 'onUpdate' is called everytime user clicks recipe card item, 'onGetViewFactory' is only called when I go back to home screen.

**onGetViewFactory**
Basically, data is lost on the above part of the code where I can not get list of ingredient objects from intent.getSerializableExtra.

```
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = (List<Ingredient>) intent.getSerializableExtra("ingredients");
        if (ingredients != null){
            Log.d("ingredients",ingredients.get(0).getIngredient());
        }
        return new RecipeWidgetRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
```

So far, onUpdate() method in provider class is properly called with list of ingredient objects. When I put those objects as intent Extra and try to pass those in remoteviews.setRemoteAdapter something goes wrong. Thank you in advance for reading this. Any advice from you would save my day. For better understanding, please feel free to clone my project and run.

[My github repo for this project](https://github.com/kdy304g/Baking-App)

Comment: Did you got it to work ? am having a similar issue.